Canonical Identification of Tangent Vector of Matrix Lie Group
Question Setup
(See edits made for comments below)
In an abstract sense, one of the defintions that we can use to define a tangent vector at a point $p\in M$, where $M$ is a differential manifold $(M,\mathscr{A})$, is that for a chart $(U,\varphi)$ with $p\in U$ and a path $\gamma(t), \gamma(0) = p$ we have:
$$ X_p(f) =\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \gamma(t))|_{t=0}$$
Where $f\in C^{\infty}_{M}:M \to \mathbb{R}$ is any smooth function (defined by the chart transition composition). We can then further use a chart-induced basis to define the bases $X^{i}_p$ along chart-induced curves $\gamma_i (t)$:
$$ X^{i}_p(f) =\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(f\circ \varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}))|_{\mathbf{x}=\varphi(p)}$$
So if we take $f$ out to define the tangent vector as a functional, then we get the expression for a general tangent vector:
$$ X_p[\cdot] = \frac{d}{dt}([\cdot]\circ \gamma(t))|_{t=0} =X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}([\cdot]\circ \varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{x}))|_{\mathbf{x}=\varphi(p)}$$
And that abstractly acts as a derivation on functions, and as it is a derivative it guarantees the Leibniz rule and is hence a tangent vector in $T_pM$. We require the test function $f$ in the expression because there is no sense of differentiability directly on the manifold. For compactness, people then write:
$$X_p = X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$
But the actual meaning is still a functional where we compose the inverse chart like before.
I am unsure of this, but at this point there is no notion of the "type" of object these abstract derivatives, right?
Concrete Example Setup
However, if we now suppose that $M=G$, a matrix Lie group, then because matrix objects are used, they come with addition and multiplication in-built (whether or not each operation forms a group is another issue), so we can define differentiation. For my specific example, let's use $SE(2)$ at identity, where:
$$\gamma_1(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(t)       & -\sin(t) & 0 \\
    \sin(t)       & \cos(t) & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
And just to be extremely concrete and clear, we choose the chart:
$$\varphi\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta)       & -\sin(\theta) & p_x \\
    \sin(\theta)       & \cos(\theta) & p_y \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right) = (\theta,p_x,p_y)$$
Then just by evaluating the derivative (actual derivative) of $\gamma_1(t)$, we get:
$$\dot{\gamma}_1(0)=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & -1 & 0 \\
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Which is technically a generator of the SE(2) Lie algebra, but I am still confused about this so I will avoid using that terminology.
Actual Questions:
The question is then - is the actual matrix above the tangent vector at $T_eG$? Is $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$, or is it $\mathfrak{g} \cong T_eG$ with an isomorphism? Because if they are not equal, then maybe the matrix itself is in $\mathfrak{g}$, while $T_eG$ is the actual abstract vector?
Restated another way, the question basically boils down to trying to see if this is true:
$$\dot{\gamma}_1(0)=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & -1 & 0 \\
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{d}{dt}([\cdot]\circ \gamma_1(t))|_{t=0} =\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}([\cdot]\circ \varphi^{-1}(\theta,p_x,p_y))|_{(0,0,0)}$$

If this is not true, then is the discrepancy in equating the matrix to
the functional?
If this is true, then how can I relate those expressions together? How can a matrix act as a functional on smooth functions $f$? What even is the action of a matrix on $f$?
For a matrix Lie group, are tangent vectors even matrices? Can they be represented by matrices?
Whatever the answer is to the above, does that mean I can/cannot relate matrices to other places not specifically at identity?

Another attempt or lead to right answer
I have seen in a little snippet of Loring W. Tu's book (Introduction to Smooth Manifolds) p. 181 example 16.7, Tu claims that for $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ which is a subset of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ there is a canonical identification:
$$\sum_{i,j}{a_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}}} \leftrightarrow [a_{ij}]$$
So what this implies is the tangent space, even for matrix Lie groups, is NOT built up of matrices, but only "represented" by them?
But this intuition also breaks down when applied to my case, because then I would be reading my generator as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & -1 & 0 \\
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \leftrightarrow -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{12}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{21}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}([\cdot]\circ \varphi^{-1}(\theta,p_x,p_y))|_{(0,0,0)}$$
That almost seems fine, but then I realise: what even is $x_{ij}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}}$ when my chart has only three coordinates $(\theta,p_x,p_y)$ where multiple elements in the matrix are dependent on that coordinate? Is there a version of this that makes sense in $SE(n)$?
TL;DR : What is the canonical identification that I can make to get from a matrix to the abstract derivatives for tangent vectors? And if possible, can anyone help show me the concrete example for that identification in my specific example?
Side note - logical progression
Once this works, I plan to try to use it to prove that for the left translation map $L_g(a)= ga$:
$$(L_g)_*(X_p) = g X_p$$
The real issue is since I don't know if $X_p$ is a matrix or not, the furthest I get is:
$$(L_g)_*(X_p)[\cdot] = \frac{d}{dt}([\cdot]\circ g \gamma(t))|_{t=0}$$
And apparently it is supposed to simplify to (according to Tu):
$$(L_g)_*(X_p)[\cdot] = g X_p [\cdot]$$
So dropping the brackets gives:
$$(L_g)_*(X_p) = g X_p$$
And at this point, I am no longer sure if these are matrices, or tangent vectors, or representations of tangent vectors using matrices.
But after I nail this and "derive" (or motivate) the exponential map I will be happy.
Disclaimer : I am an engineer and don't understand maths too well, but I am trying to go a bit deeper so forgive me if I mess up definitions. I am aiming to use this to analyse nonlinear dynamics, but found that the literature in the engineering space just forces you to accept the rules with no understanding.
I am sorry for the messy thoughts - so many concepts are tied together that I found it really hard to write. Thank you so much for helping!
EDIT FOR COMMENTS
I unfortunately don't understand much about vector fields and invariance - that is a topic I am trying to work on, but I am currently confused about vectors themselves even before they become a field. If any of my definitions in the setup are completely wrong please do inform me.
I chose to learn this definition for a tangent vector because it was the most concrete-looking and elementary definition, which helps someone like me with no rigorous math background understand it. Sorry about this, I am currently actively trying to learn these concepts but they are all tied together in one big mess, so I am having a hard time deciphering it.
Of course, if this is just the wrong way to go about it and there's no choice then I will try my best to change my way of thinking too - please tell me. It just seems a lot easier for someone with an engineering background to understand.
Thank you so much to everyone who answered, I really appreciate your help!

In regard to some of your actual questions, The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of some matrix Lie group $G$ is precisely equal to the tangent space at the identity with the addition of an appropriate bracket operation. That is;
$$\mathfrak{g} = (T_eG, [\cdot \space, \cdot])$$
The typical way that this equivalence is established is by considering the set $L(G)$ of Left-Invariant vector fields on $G$.
Let $(G,*)$ be an arbitrary Lie group. Consider the diffeomorphism;
$$l_g :G\rightarrow G \\ \small h \rightarrow g * h$$
Additionally, consider the push-forward of some arbitrary vector field $X$ on the manifold $G$;
$$(l_{g})_*(X)(f)=X(f \circ l_g)$$
The vector fields that remain unchanged by this pushforward map are the vector fields $X$ for which we have;
$$(l_g)_*(X_h)(f)=X_{g * h}(f)$$
$$\therefore X(f\circ l_g)(h)=X(f)(g * h)=X(f)\circ l_g(h)$$
This must hold for all $h \in G$ and for all $f\in C^{\infty}(G)$. So, our Left-Invariant vector fields must obey the following equation;
$$X(f\circ l_g)=\big[X(f)\big]\circ l_g$$
As it turns out (and this can easily be proven) the Left-Invariant vector fields on $G$ form an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space for which the commutator;
$$[X,Y]=XY-YX$$
closes on $L(G)$. Therefore, $(L(G), [\cdot , \cdot])$ forms an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. Now, we can construct an isomorphism between $L(G)$ and $T_eG$ as vector spaces by considering the map;
$$j: T_eG \rightarrow L(G) \\ \small A \rightarrow j(A)$$
where we have;
$$j(A)_g:= (l_g)_*A \\ \small \forall g \in G$$
I will not bother proving that this map turns out to produce Left-Invariant vector fields but I will show that it is bijective;
$$\textbf{Injective}$$
$$j(A)=j(B) \iff \\  j(A)_g = j(B)_g \space\space \forall g\in G \implies \\ j(A)_e = j(B)_e \iff \\ (l_e)_*(A)=(l_e)_*(B) \iff \\ A=B$$
$$\textbf{Surjective}$$
Let $X$ be a Left-Invariant vector field on $G$ and consider the vector $X_e \in T_eG$. We then have;
$$j(X_e)_g=(l_g)_*(X_e)=X_g \space\space (\forall g \in G)$$
$$\therefore j(X_e)=X \space\space\small (\forall X\in L(G))$$
Therefore, we have that $T_eG \cong L(G)$ as a vector space. If we then define;
$$[[\cdot \space, \cdot]]: T_eG \times T_eG \rightarrow T_eG \\ (A,B) \rightarrow j^{\space -1}([j(A), j(B)])$$
We can then conclude that $T_eG \cong L(G)$ as a Lie Algebra. From here we then arrive rather naturally at the definition of the exponential map;
$$\exp: T_eG \rightarrow G \\ \small A \rightarrow \exp(A):=\gamma^A(1)$$
Where $\gamma^A(t)$ is the unique integral curve of the Left-Invariant vector field $j(A)$ for which we have $\gamma^A(0)=e$.
$$\textbf{EDIT:}$$
Firstly, is important to remember that a differential operator does not map a function to a real number... it maps a function to another function that must then be evaluated at some point $p$ on your manifold. So when I write something like;
$$X(f)\circ l_g(h)$$
That is saying to let the vector field $X$ act on the function $f$ and then evaluate the resulting function at the point $g*h \in G$.
Secondly, Differential operators on a manifold $M$ generate infinitesimal transformations in the coordinate system. For example, the operator;
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$
​
generates an infinitesimal displacement in the $x^i$ direction.
In a Lie group setting, an element $X \in \mathfrak{g}$
can be seen as generating an infinitesimal flow on the group manifold. The matrix $X$ generates a one-parameter family of group elements
${g(t)}$, where $g(t)=\exp(tX)$.
The matrices in the Lie algebra can be understood as analogous to differential operators because they also act on functions (or more generally, on other Lie group elements) and generate infinitesimal changes. In this sense, a matrix in the Lie algebra provides a basis for the tangent space at the identity, just as a differential operator acts as a basis for the tangent space at a point on a manifold.
$$\textbf{EDIT 2:}$$
We have seen that any given vector $X_e\in T_eG$ generates a Left-Invariant vector field $X\in L(G)$ and that the exponential map $\exp: T_eG \rightarrow G$ is defined as the unique integral curve of this vector field $X$ through the identity element $e\in G$. Recall that for a general manifold $M$ we can define the tangent space at a point $p \in M$ as an equivalence class of curves thusly;
$$v(f):=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \gamma)|_0$$
Where $\gamma(0) = p$.
We can provide an analogous treatment for a matrix Lie group $G$ thusly;
$$X(f):=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \exp(tX))|_{0}$$
Where $\exp(0) = e\in G$. Utilizing a coordinate chart $x^i_j: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ then allows us to write;
$$X(f):=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ (x^i_j)^{-1}\circ (x^i_j)\circ \exp(tX))|_{0}$$
$$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i_j}\bigg|_e \cdot \frac{d}{dt}({x^i_j} \circ \exp(tX))|_{0}$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}[\exp(tX)]^i_j|_{0} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_j}\bigg|_e(f)$$
Which reveals our final expression;
$$X(f):=X^i_j \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_j}\bigg|_e(f)$$
$$\textbf{FINAL EDIT:}$$
Lets now consider some $2 \times 2$ matrix Lie group $G$ and the function;
$$\det:G \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
Now, let $X$ be some arbitrary element of the Lie algebra associated with $G$. Then we have;
$$X(\det)=X^i_j \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_j}\bigg|_e(\det)$$
For a $2 \times 2$ matrix we have;
$$\det(M)=M^1_1M^2_2-M^1_2M^2_1$$
So we will have;
$$X(\det)= X^1_1 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1_1}(x^1_1x^2_2-x^1_2x^2_1)\big|_e+X^1_2 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1_2}(x^1_1x^2_2-x^1_2x^2_1)\big|_e \\ \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space +X^2_1 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2_1}(x^1_1x^2_2-x^1_2x^2_1)\big|_e+ X^2_2\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2_2}(x^1_1x^2_2-x^1_2x^2_1)\big|_e$$
Which will yield;
$$X(\det)=X^1_1+X^2_2 = \text{Tr}(X)$$
So the action of some arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrix Lie algebra element on the determinant function at the identity simply gives us the trace of that Lie algebra matrix. This can be shown more cleanly by being more general but I wanted you to see how the differential operator with respect to the matrix components acts upon some matrix function. Of course, when acting on an element $g\in G$ we will simply have;
$$X(g)=\frac{d}{dt}(g\circ \exp(tX))|_0$$
$$=g \circ X\exp(tX)|_0$$
$$=g \circ X$$
as expected.

I'm very sorry, but I don't quite understand the notion of "left-invariance" because I haven't gotten very deep into it. From what you wrote, you had $X(f \circ l_g)=(l_g)_{*}(X)(f)$ apply onto another group member - how is this possible? If that expression is the pushforward of a vector, then it must also be another vector in a different tangent space. This then means that it must map functions to the real numbers, right? so how can you "apply" the group member $h$ to it in the expression $X(f \circ l_g)(h)$?
I am also still puzzled by the identification of a matrix to a local derivative.

@EmailsAreHorrible Hope the edits make a few things more clear...

@EmailsAreHorrible It is precisely the pushforward but acting on a vector field not just a tangent vector. To frame it in terms of tangent vectors, $X$ is a function sending points in the Lie group to tangent vectors $X(h) \in T_hG$. The point is that pushforward by $l_g$ sends $X(h)$ to $X(gh)$.

@Callum Oh so then if $X$ is a vector FIELD, then we have to specify where the vector is first, hence taking $g\in G$ as an input? So THEN after $X(g)$ we can then use it to send $f$ to a scalar (the directional derivative at that point) such that $X(g)[f] \to \mathbb{R}$? I haven't studied vector fields enough yet, but you are saying that the pushforward of left translation maps $X(h) \in T_h G$ to $X(gh) \in T_{gh}G$ right? I will try to read up more on vector fields, sorry about that.

@Volk After a bit more thinking, I believe I see what you mean but am not too sure. Are you saying that a vector field $X(\cdot)[\cdot]$ that takes in a point in $G$ to specify where to evaluate the vector, which then takes in a function $f$ to finally map it to $\mathbb{R}$? Sorry if I swap the brackets. And there is a (?) specific vector field where $(l_g)_* (X)$ at $h$ is the same as $X$ at $gh$?, because this property isn't guaranteed for all vector fields?

@Volk But the most crucial part of your edit that I want to address is you mention : "matrices in the Lie algebra can be understood as analogous to differential operators because they also act on functions". Can you please explain how this can be the case? If you take my example SE(2) generator matrix as an example, can you show me how that matrix physically and computationally acts on a function? That matrix is at identity (so we ignore vector fields for now), so if possible a direct computation using any scalar function would be amazing - I should see the result as a real number right?

@EmailsAreHorrible You got it... The left invariant vector fields are precisely the vector fields for which the push-forward map $l_{g*}$ leave the entire vector field unchanged which means that $l_{g*}X_h=X_{gh}$ for all $h\in G$. In regards to your question of how exactly a Matrix Lie Algebra element would act on a function I'll make a second edit to my post.

@Volk From your example, I do feel like it is super close. However, I still run into the problem as you see in my original post - you make the same identification (or similar) as Tu, but the issue is that there is still a $x^{i}_{j}$. In my SE(2) example, $\varphi(p) = (x^1(p), x^2(p),...)$ - which is a "vector" (collection of coordinates), not a matrix. So I am unable to tell what these indices mean. Could you explicitly (basically compute) for my example, write out how the matrix [0,-1,0;1,0,0;0,0,0] with my choice of coordinates $(\theta, p_x, p_y)$ acts on a function f? Thank you so much.

@Volk It also seems to me that the problem may have to do with $\varphi(p)=x^i$ not being a matrix. However, that shouldn't matter though due to chart independence and because SE(2) IS isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. The issue ends up being that if my chart is $x^i$ (like SE(2)), where the chart is more complex(e.g. functions of the matrix entries like SE(2) for $\theta$ as stated in my post), this all breaks down. The two problems thus are: 1. I don't have a sum over matrix entries. 2. The derivative I have to take is NOT just over each matrix element slot. Could you please help resolve this?

@Volk Thank you for your final edit, I also seem to have figured it too. If my chart is $x^k$ isntead of $x^i_j$ then there is still an identification to be made. If we have (before any assumptions) $\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\gamma (t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\cdot \frac{dx^k}{dt}$ then because $x^k(t)=x^k(\gamma_{ij}(t))$ is a differentiable matrix, we have $\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\gamma (t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\cdot \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \gamma_{ij}}\cdot [\frac{d \gamma_{ij}}{dt}]$ - that shows an isomorphism between the matrix and the tangent in the brackets $[\cdot]$.

@EmailsAreHorrible Awesome... Glad I could help. I know this subject can be a little indecipherable with all of the abstraction in the literature. Feel free to accept either my answer or Deane's... whichever you found more helpful.

@Volk If you believe that my identification is correct then this is solved! This also fixes the pushforward issue if my logic is correct! Thank you so much for your help! I do say though, that by my logic the tangent vectors and matrices are different objects, but are related via linear isomorphism so at that point it doesn't matter, which is probably why noone bothered to put this in their textbook. I may need help again when the exponential map comes so I may have to ask again :(

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand\M{\mathcal{M}}$
MORE BRIEF COMMENTS:

A tangent vector at $M \in G$ is a matrix.

Example: Let $$G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} :\ \theta \in \R \right \}. $$ Given any function $\theta: (-a,a) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, you get a curve $$ c(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta(t) & -\sin\theta(t) \\ \sin\theta(t) & \cos\theta(t) \end{bmatrix}.$$ Then the velocity vector at $c(0)$ is $$c'(0) = \begin{bmatrix} -\sin\theta(0) & -\cos\theta(0)\\ \cos(\theta(0) & -\sin\theta(0)\end{bmatrix}\theta'(0).$$ If $c(0)=e$, then $$c'(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\theta'(0) \\ \theta'(0) & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ For any $a \in \R$, there is a curve such that $\theta'(0)=a$. Therefore, $$ \mathfrak{g} = T_eG = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -a \\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}:\ a \in \R \right\}. $$

The exponential map $$\exp: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G $$ is defined using the Taylor series of $e^x$: For each $A \in \mathfrak{g}$, $$\exp(A) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}. $$ Two things need to be proved:
a) For each $A \in \mathfrak{g}$, the series converges (absolutely)
b) If $A \in \mathfrak{g}$, then $\exp(A) \in G$.
It is a worthwhile exercise to show this is true for the example in 2).


bRESPONSE TO COMMENT:
First, unless you really want to learn the rigorous foundations of abstract differential geometry, you can safely avoid the concept and definition of derivations.
But here is, I hope, a clarifiction. By the definition given below of a tangent vector, there is a natural way to associate to any $A \in T_MG \subset \M$ a derivation $D_A$ as follows: By the definition of a tangent vector, there exists a parameterized curve $c$ such that $c(0)=M$ and $c'(0)=A$. For each smooth function $f: G \rightarrow \R$, define
$$D_A(f) = (f\circ c)'(0).$$
In other words, $D_A(f)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $A$ at $M\in G$.
The product rule implies that $D_A$ is a derivation. The nontrivial fact is that given any derivation $D$ at $M \in G$, there exists a matrix $A \in T_MG$ such that $D = D_A$. So
$$T_MG = \{\text{velocity vectors}\} = \{\text{derivations}\}.
$$
ORIGINAL POST:
Since your questions are about a matrix group, everything can be done very concretely. If $G$ is a matrix group and $M \in G$, we can consider smooth curves $c: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow G$ such that $c(0)=M_0$. The velocity at $t=0$ of this curve, $c'(0)$ is a matrix. The set of all matrices that arise as the velocity of a curve through $M$ is the tangent space of $G$ at $M$,
$$ T_MG = \{ c'(0):\ c: (-\delta,\delta)\rightarrow G\text{ such that }c(0)=M\} $$
The standard definition of the the Lie algebra of $G$ is $$\mathfrak{g} = T_eG. $$
Note, however, that for each $M \in G$, there is a natural linear isomorphism
$$ L_M: T_eG \rightarrow T_MG, $$
where given $A \in T_eG$, let $c(t)$ be a curve in $G$ such that $c(0)=e$ and $c'(0) = A$, let $$c_M(t) = Mc(t)$$ and define
$$ L_M(A) = c_M'(0) = Mc'(0) = MA. $$
Therefore, given any $A \in \mathfrak{g}$, you get a vector field $V_A$ on $G$, where for each $M \in G$, $$ V_A(M) = L_M(A) = MA. $$ Such a vector field is called left invariant. This defines a natural isomorphism between the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and the space of left invariant vector fields.
So if you want to do calculations on a matrix group and its Lie algebra, the naive obvious approach generally works.

As in other comments, I really apologise - I don't know much about vector fields and the concept of invariance so I don't quite understand what it means to have a natural isomorphism between $\mathfrak{g}$ and "the space of left invariant vector fields".
However, I am interested in when you say "the velocity of this curve $c'(0)$" is a matrix", because to define a velocity we need a tangent vector, but in the abstract definition it is a point derivation. What I am asking is - how is a matrix a point derivation? How does it apply to a function $f$ so that it satisfies the Leibiz rule?

As for a left invariant vector field, let's start with what is a vector field. A vector field associates to each matrix $M \in G$, a matrix $A(M) \in T_MG$. It's the analogue of a vector field on, say, a surface (such as the sphere) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In my answer, I show how a tangent vector $A \in T_eG$ can be used to define a tangent vector $A(M) \in T_MG$. It is done by taking a curve through $e$, multiplying each point on the curve on the left by $M$. This is called left invariant because given any $M, N \in G$, $A(MN) = MA(N)$.

So in your definition, is $D_a$ the tangent vector, or is $A$ the tangent vector? I was under the impression that $D_a$ was the tangent vector itself - I am not sure how a matrix can even be considered as a pointwise derivation, because I don't know how it can act on a function $f$. As for your comment, are you saying $A$ itself is a vector field? If yes, can I interpret $A\in T_eG$ as shorthand for $A(\mathbb{I})$? I also see how $A(MN)=MA(N)$ if I take for granted that the pushforward is equivalent to left multiplication. But what importance does this equation have?

There are two distinct ways to define what a tangent vector is (velocity of a curve or derivation at a point) and there is a natural isomorphism mapping between them. So in a sense a tangent vector is simultaneously both. Or you can think of it as being one but has an alternate description.

In this context, a matrix $A$ can be considered as a derivation at $M$ if there exists a curve $c$ passing through $M$ such that $c(0) = M$ and $c'(0)=A$. If $G$ is not the group of all invertible matrices, then not every matrix $A$ defines a derivation at $M$.

Please keep in mind that here "vector" is a term in abstract differential geometry but in this explicit context, a "vector" is always a matrix. Let's distinguish between a tangent vector (matrix) $A \in T_eG$ and a vector (matrix) field $\mathbf{A}$. If you have a vector (matrix) field $\mathbf{A}$, then indeed you could write $A = \mathbf{A}(e)$. If you start with a matrix $A \in T_eG$, then it can be extended to a left invariant vector field $\mathbf{A}$, where $\mathbf{A}(e) = A$.
